# What are the possible values of the integers $x, y , z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

So the question is 
Let $x,y, z$ Be digits so that the $9$-digit number  $5x36y98z2$ is divisible by $792$.

$1) ~$ Without calculating $x$ and $y$, explain why $z = 3$ or $ 7$.

$2)~$ Without calculating $x$, show that $y = 0$ or $9$.

$3)~$ Find all combinations of $x, y, z$

Comment: x = 5, y = 9, z = 7

Comment: Hint for (1): 792 is divisible by 8.

Comment: By the same person?  I’m not sure why the accepted answer was accepted. Finding the values of x, y, and z with a computer program does not answer (1) or (2).